# Send 2d array using MPI

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, mpi

I've been trying so hard to achieve to parallelize using MPI and C++ the computation for a discretized domain for the Burger's equation.

I've been following other questions asked in this page, but I am not obtaining the desired results. At this moment, I've simplified the problem by working with 2 processors and I am only sending and receiving to the rank in the right and in the left.

In order, to initialize the 2d array I've used this function:

```
double **alloc_2d_int(int rows, int cols) {
    double *data = (double *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double));
    double **array= (double **)malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}
```

Here a temporal vector is initialized to zeros. In increase the size by 2 in order to have ghost shell where I can situate the columns and rows received from the other ranks and use them to compute the central difference in the values situated in the edges.

```
temp = alloc_2d_int(Ny_P+2,Nx_P+2);
           for (unsigned i=0; i < Ny_P+2; i++)
        {
            for (unsigned j=0; j < Nx_P+2; j++)
            {
               temp[i][j]=0;               
            }
        }
```

I simplified the problem filling the domain with only 1.

```
 for (unsigned i=1; i < Ny_P+1; i++)
        {
            for (unsigned j=1; j < Nx_P+1; j++)
            {
               temp[i][j]=1;
            }
        }
```

Then at each time step I will be receiving and sending. I am only working now by sending and receiving to the right and left.

```
            MPI_Issend(&(temp[Ny_P][1]), Nx_P, MPI_DOUBLE, rankright, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request5);
            MPI_Irecv(&(temp[0][1]), Nx_P, MPI_DOUBLE, rankleft, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request6);
            MPI_Issend(&(temp[1][1]), Nx_P, MPI_DOUBLE, rankleft, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request7);
            MPI_Irecv(&(temp[Ny_P+1][1]), Nx_P, MPI_DOUBLE, rankright, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request8);
```

In theory, in this case, I want to send columns horizontally, but it is placing a row instead, and I am obtaining this results:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A371k.png)

I know that the problem is in the memory layout in how is structured, but I tried several ways to point to the data and I am not been able to obtain the results.

Really appreciate your help.

Cheers!:)

Answer (score 0):

Simple advice here. If you are doing MPI, that usually means HPC, so you want to to use a 1D array instead and access it with a 2D function/macro.

And this will also lead to one MPI call instead of one per row or column, so relaly no reason at all to use a array of pointers to arrays.

Comment: Hi Matthieu,I tried to use 1d arrays of the shape [i*Nx+j], but I had not been able to send and receive properly, so I switched to this type of arrays to sort it out.

Comment: the shape is probably not [i*Nx+j]! You usually send to another rank full rows, or full columns, so the shape should be multiples of Nx.